# Ubuntu 14.04 hard drive partitioning help wanted

Tags: ubuntu, partition, system-installation, encryption

I'm in need of some assistance with manual partitioning from the Ubuntu 14.04 install GUI.

I'm trying to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. I have a 60GB SSD as that I want all my OS files on (root, home, etc.), and then I have 3 2TB HDDs that I want to partition so I can later configure them into a raid5 array using MDADM.

I want my 60GB drive to be encrypted as well as my 3-drive raid array. What would be the easiest way of doing this? Should I use the default encryption for the SSD and encrypt my raid drives later on once I have the raid array configured? Do I encrypt the raid array or the 3 individual drives?

I'm new to the Ubuntu manual partitioning and don't quite understand how to assign mount points and how to size swap partitions. I've also had trouble with disk alignment in the past regarding the raid array disks. Any support at all would be greatly appreciated.

If anyone could link some tutorials or give me a quick walk-through on partitioning with multiple drives it would be much appreciated.

Overview of request (for clarity):

Drive1 (SSD 60GB): Encrypted, Boot Drive (/, /home, etc.)

Drive2 (HDD 2TB): Disk1 Raid Array Drive3 (HDD 2TB): Disk2 Raid Array Drive4 (HDD 2TB): Disk3 Raid Array Raid Array: Encrypted

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking. Have you tried to follow the on-screen instructions? Is already a no brainier. Just create your partitions, assign the mount point, and install. Through you probably are better off with the automated installation.

Answer (score 1):

> I want my 60GB drive to be encrypted as well as my 3-drive raid array. What would be the easiest way of doing this?
>
> Should I use the default encryption for the SSD and encrypt my raid drives later on once I have the raid array configured?

Short answer - Yes.

During the install process, Ubuntu will ask if you want to encrypt your home folder, which I've done and seems to work OK. That doesn't encrypt system files, of course, but if you have sensitive info, you can put it in your home folder and softlink it out (e.g. `ln -s /home/<username>/www /var/www`)

> Do I encrypt the raid array or the 3 individual drives?

I think you have little choice but to encrypt the filesystem on the array as a whole, unless you have a fancy RAID controller than can encrypt the individual volumes - which you probably don't, since you're thinking of md ;)

I would keep it simple and create a plain ol' unencrypted filesystem. Then use TrueCrypt to create a "filesystem-inside-a-file" kind of setup. You can also encrypt individual files, which, depending on your use case, may be a better balance of speed and simplicity.